# Какие есть примеры использования GoF шаблонов в .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования

Интересны не кастомные реализации, а именно примеры использования в .NET, написал то где сразу приходит в голову пример:

1. Proxy
2. Bridge
3. Facade
4. Adapter
5. Composite
6. Flyweight
7. Decorator
8. State
9. Memento
10. Command
11. Visitor
12. Strategy
13. Iterator - foreach keyword
14. Observer
15. Mediator
16. Interpreter
17. Template method
18. Chain of responsibility - ASP .NET Core middleware
19. Builder - WebApplicationBuilder
20. Prototype
21. Singleton
22. Factory Method
23. Abstract Factory

Comment: Сами то понимаете объем ответа на этот вопрос? Вы написали оглавление к книжке размером с томик "Война и мир". В чем именно у вас проблема? Вы не можете написать код ни для одного из них? Зачем вам все сразу? Половиной вы примерно никогда в жизни не воспользуетесь. Для большинства важен контекст реализации, абстрактный шаблон зачастую сам по себе ничего полезного не несет, а вот его применение к какому-либо решению - да.

Comment: Зачем вам это? Вот, например, класс [File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) является фасадом для `FileStream` и `StreamWriter`. Что вы будете делать с этой информацией?

Comment: Понимаю, приблизительно. Если для 3 примеров паттернов я использовал 7 слов, то для остальных еще около 50 слов нужно. Проблемы нет, есть любознательность. Могу для каждого написать код, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: `примеры использования в .NET` расшифруйте в таком случае, что для вас пример использования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov видимо он собирает доказательства, что GoF нисколько не устарел и имеет место даже в современном программировании. И ищет примеры использования в реальных проектах/библиотеках (а не примеры реализации). И примеров этих тысячи ибо оно везде, но вот попробуй вспомни где конкретно. И по теме 15 Mediator - Mediatr 11 Visitor - System.Linq.Expressions (там даже есть ExpressionVisitor), 6 Flyweight - Dependency Property

Comment: Думаю, это то https://stackoverflow.com/a/28868953

Comment: YD359, это то что нужно